# Java JPA annotation @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED) not working as expected

Tags: java

Running J2EE application on JBoss 5.1 using Hibernate. I need to call some methods (in quartz scheduler) that use explicit database connections from an enterprise bean. Currently get an error about calling commit not allowed in a transaction.

I was hoping that adding the `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)` annotation to the bean method would allow me to call quartz api, but still get the same exception. Am I misunderstanding what this annotation means, or is something else going on?

```
2014-06-23 17:43:41,184 ERROR [http-0.0.0.0-8443-4] org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't commit jdbc connection. You cannot commit during a managed transaction! [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit during a managed transaction!]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.commitConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3661)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3799)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.executeInLock(JobStoreTX.java:93)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeWithoutLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3703)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.checkExists(JobStoreSupport.java:1897)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.checkExists(QuartzScheduler.java:1491)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.checkExists(StdScheduler.java:555)
```

Some more data:

1) If I call my managed bean method from a non-managed class without the annotation, then I get the same exception (transaction is created)

2) If I call my managed bean method from a non-managed class with the annotation then I dont get the exception (no transaction created)

3) If I call my managed bean method from another managed bean or from itself, then I get the exception with or without the annotation (transaction exists)

So the annotation does seem to prevent a new transaction being created, but it does not seem to suspend an already existing transaction (or maybe I am getting this all wrong).

Comment: The annotation is for container managed transactions. The container managed transactions cannot be demarcated (committed/rolled back) by the bean.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. I want the container to suspend the transaction for this method, thats all.

Comment: *Currently get an error about calling commit not allowed in a transaction.* You are getting exception while committing transaction. The usage of `@TransactionAttribute` means that you are using CMT (container managed transaction). The problem is that when you are using CMT, container will commit the trasaction and you are not allowed to commit it.

Comment: Please read this - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html, and get some understanding.

Comment: But isnt the point of the annotation to tell the container to suspend the transaction at that method?

Comment: The point is not whether or not an on going transaction is suspended. *java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit during a managed transaction!* The actual problem that the quartz is somehow trying to commit the a transaction that is managed by the container.

Comment: Probably the quartz is not configured the way it's supposed to be for your scenario. It either should not use the container managed transaction or if it's going to use the container managed transaction than it should let the container do the commit/rollback.

Comment: Quartz is configured to use a non-JTA data source, so it shouldnt be using the container transaction at all.

Comment: How do you configure the quartz datasource?

Comment: Also, *Quartz is configured to use a non-JTA data source, so it shouldnt be using the container transaction at all.* If you really think so then why are you trying to **suspend** the ongoing transaction?

Comment: I am using quartz JobStoreTX jobstore class and using the JBoss DefaultDS as the datastore.

Comment: I think you should let quartz create it's own data source instead of feeding it the one from JBoss, at least to see how does that work.

Comment: Unfortunately you cant, you have to give it one.

Comment: Actually, you can do that - http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigDataSources.

Comment: You are correct, I will try sometime to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit during a managed transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540892/java-sql-sqlexception-you-cannot-commit-during-a-managed-transaction)