# java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit during a managed transaction

Tags: java, jboss, datasource

In jboss 7, I have below config

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/env/esilicon/vms/OracleDBPoolNonXA" pool-name="ExampleDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@erptstdb.sc.kaka.com:14100:ERPTST</connection-url>
    <driver>XAOracleJDBCDriver</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>apps</user-name>
        <password>apps</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="XAOracleJDBCDriver" module="oracle.jdbc">
        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

In orther class, I've method to get the connection for datasource

```
public static Connection getNonXAConnection() {
    try {
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)context.lookup(JNDILookup.PURE_CONNECTION_JNDI);
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.fatal(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
    return null;
}
```

The error occur when I commit this connection

```
java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit during a managed transaction!
 at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.jdbcCommit(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:981)
 at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.commit(WrappedConnection.java:757)
```

I just like to get connection and execute some stored procedure, and finnaly commit this connection. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Use an anotation like this:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
public class SchedulerBean {
```

I was facing same problem with Quartz and was able to solve this way.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when specifying an incorrect remoting address in the standalone.xml file. The value should normally be:

```
<socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
```

This value should be set to the port address **before** any offset applied using the **-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset**=xxx option in the startup script.